# I am keep getting a NoMethodError in Wines#new - anyone know what the issue is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I only have one model (a wine model) and an index page that displays all the current wines and how many bottles I have for them. I have all my views set up and I just want to track the name of the wine and the number of bottles of wine. However, I keep getting an error that says NoMethodError in Wines#new when I click "Create A New Wine" and says there is something wrong with line #2 in my _form.html.erb file. But I can't find what the problem is.

Here is what my _form.html.erb file looks like:

```
 <%= form_for @wine do |form| %>
 <div>Name: <%= form.text_field :name %></div></br>
 <div>Number: <%= form.text_field :number %></div></br>
 <%= form.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

My index.html.erb file:

```
<h1>VIEWING ALL WINES</h1>
<!-- INDEX -->

<div class="buttons"> <%= link_to '<button type="button">Create a New      Wine</button>'.html_safe, new_wine_path %></div>
<div class="container">
<h1><% @wines.each do |item| %></h1>
<div class="text">
  <div>
    <h3>NAME: <a href="wines/<%= item['id'] %>"><%= item['name'] %></a></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><B>NUMBER OF BOTTLES: </b><%= item['number'] %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Wines_Controller.rb file:

```
class WinesController < ApplicationController

# INDEX --------------------------
  @wines = Wine.all
#  @wines = "wines index working"
end

# NEW -------------------------
 def new
 #  render text: "new working"
 @wine = Wine.new
 end

# CREATE --------------------------

def create
#  render text: "create working"
@wine = Wine.create(wine_params)
redirect_to wines_path
end

# EDIT --------------------------
def edit
#  render text: "edit working"
@wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
end

# UPDATE --------------------------
def update
#  render text: "update working"
@wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
@wine.update_attributes(wine_params)
redirect_to wines_path
end

# SHOW --------------------------
def show
#  render text: "show working"
@wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
end

# DESTROY --------------------------
def destroy
#  render text: "destroy working"
@nwine = Wine.find(params[:id])
@wine.destroy
redirect_to wines_path
end

# STRONG PARAMS --------------------
def wine_params
    params.require(:wine).permit(:name, :number)
end
```

end

Comment: def index is missing in your controller, do u know that?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally left it out and just added it, same problem.

Comment: I do not think that was the issue

Comment: Did you try to comment the 2nd line out and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use button inside link, you can use button_to inside of it, like this. And also button usually use post method, not get method like link_to, you can do something like this.

```
<%= button_to "Create a New Wine", new_wine_path, class: "button", method: :get %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying there is no `create` method, and it's true. Change this:

```
@wine = Wine.create(wine_params)
```

for this

```
@wine = Wine.new(wine_params)
if @wine.save
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

---

Also, I recommend you to put

```
def wine_params
    params.require(:wine).permit(:name, :number)
end
```

into a `private` block, like this

```
private

def wine_params
    params.require(:wine).permit(:name, :number)
end
```

I guess you're trying to create a button in this line

```
<%= link_to '<button type="button">Create a New Wine </button>'.html_safe, new_wine_path %></div>
```

why not stick to a simple `link_to`? like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Create a new wine', new_wine_path %>
```

Comment: I changed everything but I keep getting the same error. It specifically highlights

Comment: Specifically highlights this: <div>Name: <%= form.text_field :name %></div></br>  ... same issue

Comment: I'd keep it like this: `<%= form.text_field :name %>` since rails add labels by default.

Comment: and remove `<div> name` and `</div></br>`

Comment: For more information on how to render forms [check the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). Anyway, apply the changes I suggested in this answer (method `create` doesn't exist) and if that answer your doubt, mark as resolved? :)